# Is it possible to use Python / BeautifulSoup to strip all tags from a chunk of HTML EXCEPT anchor / links?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a chunk of HTML and I'd like to strip all tags to leave it as plaintext EXCEPT leaving in the `<a href="url">some text<a>` links.

Is this possible / simple in BeautifulSoup?

Comment: Not an answer per se, but I suggest using readily available HTML sanitizing library, such as bleach (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bleach). `bleach.clean(html, tags=['a'], attributes={'a': ['href']}, strip=True)` would do the thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
import BeautifulSoup

doc = '''<html><head><title>Page title</title></head><body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is <i>paragraph</i> <a onclick="">one</a>.<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is <i>paragraph</i> <b>two</b>.</html>'''
soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(doc)

for tag in soup.recursiveChildGenerator():
    if isinstance(tag,BeautifulSoup.Tag) and tag.name not in ('a'):
        print(tag.string)
    elif isinstance(tag,BeautifulSoup.Tag) and tag.name in ('a'):
        print(tag)
```

Comment: Actually. Although it sort of works, it manages to double up the contents of the anchor tag ... once inside the tag, once outside. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I added an else if, try it out and let me know

Comment: What does recursiveChildGenerator actually return? An iterator of all tags? If so, some tags in my html doc are nested, so presumably that means I'll get the same content back twice. Once inside the inner tag and once inside the outer.

Is that right? 

In which case, what I need is a way to do a depth-first collapse of the html tree, rather than just an iteration through all tags.

Is there a way to do that in BS?

Comment: recursiveChildGenerator should be returning every tag in the document in the order of depth first traversal.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814317/depth-first-traversal-on-beautifulsoup-parse-tree

Are you seeing the same anchor tags duplicated or are you seeing anchor tags appear out of order?

Comment: I'm seeing various bits of *content* inside the anchor tags appearing twice. Once inside an anchor tag and once stripped of the anchor.

Comment: OK. Stepping through with the python debugger I realize that the childGenerator is top down. It starts with the *highest* level tag, then iterates DOWNWARDS.